# Implementing Google's hashbang/Ajax crawl with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, search, routes

What are best practices for implementing Google's hashbang/Ajax crawl pattern with ASP.NET MVC?

http://code.google.com/web/ajaxcrawling/docs/getting-started.html:

> the crawler will modify each AJAX URL
>   such as
>
> ```
> www.example.com/ajax.html#!key=value
> ```
>
> to temporarily become
>
> ```
> www.example.com/ajax.html?_escaped_fragment_=key=value
> ```

ASP.NET's Routing framework does not allow specifying query string parameters, but of course you can always create an action method that takes _escaped_fragment_ as a parameter (or even just look for the _escaped_fragment_ parameter in the request header).

That's a bit cumbersome however.  Is there a better way?

**UPDATE:**

I went ahead and implemented the following pattern (in my case the fragments look like a regular url path).  Again, this is hardly the cleanest approach, so any suggestions are welcome.

```
public virtual ActionResult Index(int id, string _escaped_fragment_)
{
    //Handle Google Ajax Crawler
    if (_escaped_fragment_ != null)
    {
        string[] fragments = _escaped_fragment_.Split(new char[]{'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (fragments.Length > 0)
        {
            //parse fragments
            //return static content
        }
    }
    //normal action operation
    return View();
}
```

Comment: You may want to put that in the controllers OnActionExecuting method, rather than in the action. This way you can redirect to whatever action you believe is best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write use a custom model binder which will take the `_escaped_fragment_` query string parameter and return some strongly typed model:

```
public ActionResult Index(MyModel model)
{
    // Directly use model.Id, model.Key1, model.Key2, ...
    return View();
}
```